# True value of a distribution parameter based on a single observation of its point estimator

Tags: probability, statistics

This is my first time asking a question on here so my apologies if I have unknowingly violated any rules!

I am reading from Devore's *Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences, 9e* and I am struggling to fully conceptualize something he wrote on pages 259-260:

> When the point estimator uˆ has approximately a normal distribution, which will often be the case when n is large, then we can be reasonably confident that the true value of u lies within approximately 2 standard errors (standard deviations) of uˆ.

Is Devore saying that, for any observed value of uˆ (the point estimator for the parameter u) and subject to the constraints mentioned, the actual value of u will be within 2 SDs? I figure I must be misunderstanding since 2 SDs around an observed value of uˆ that is way in the tails of the sampling distribution of uˆ would surely not capture u often, right?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It is not saying $u$ **must** be within 2 SDs of $\hat{u}$.  Instead it is saying you can be **reasonably confident** that $u$ will be within 2 SDs of $\hat{u}$.  Informally this is analogous to something like: I cannot guarantee I will be alive tomorrow, but I am reasonably confident I will be alive tomorrow.  Am I making sense?

Comment: @antkam I follow you there, but the language of "reasonably confident" seems somewhat strong. So, just to confirm what you're saying...it is not always true that u will be within 2 SDs of an observed u^? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right: It is not always true that $u$ will be within $2$ SDs of $\hat{u}$.

As to whether "reasonably confident" seems strong, I suppose you have a case.  $\pm 2$ SDs in a normal distribution amounts to just over $95\%$ of the area under the bell curve.  So, frankly, if $u$ indeed turns out to be outside of $2$ SDs of $\hat{u}$, I personally would be surprised but not shocked.  :)  If the author were using $\pm 3$ SDs, maybe "reasonably confident" would be more justified.

---

The rest of this answer goes into some technical details.  So feel free to skip if this is confusing you further instead of helping!

You might be wondering why the author uses vague words like "reasonably confident" and didn't just come out and say:

$$Prob(|u - \hat{u}| \le 2 \sigma) > 0.95$$

The reason is that the above statement is correct as a probability on $\hat{u}$, but it is technically incorrect as a probability on $u$, because of the technicality that there is no (agreed, or implicit) probability space on $u$ itself.  I.e. our surprise comes from the fact that if $u$ did turn out to be outside $\hat{u} \pm 2 \sigma$, then the particular observed value of $\hat{u}$ would have shown up with a probability $< 0.05$, but we cannot say $u$ itself is outside $\hat{u} \pm 2 \sigma$ with probability $< 0.05$ because, in the absence of a (prior) probability space on $u$, then $u$ is what it is.  In fact, this $0.95$ value has an interesting alternate name: it is both a probability on $\hat{u}$ and a *likelihood* on $u$, but technically we cannot call it a probability on $u$.

See the wikipedia article on [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) which goes beyond my brief discussion here, esp. the section on Background and Interpretation.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much for clearing this up for me. If I am interpreting things correctly, then, what we can say is that the true parameter value u will, with 95% likelihood, be within 2 SDs of of the observed value of the point estimator u^? And this is the case because the sampling distribution of u^ is centred at u and so 95% of the observations of u^ will be within 2 SDs of that centre correspondingly (given the normality assumption).

Comment: Absolutely right re: your comment.